# Is it possible to place conditions on the parameters of a method?

Tags: java, methods, parameters, conditional-statements

I'm trying to make a method that requests an int, but that this can only be between a minValue and maxValue.
The thing is. Is possible to add something that tells the user (when writting the code) that minValue will always needs to be lower than maxValue?

```
    public static int askInteger(String askedValue, int minValue, int maxValue) {
        int number = 0;
        try {
            System.out.print(askedValue);
            String text = sc.next();
            text.replace(" ", "");
            text.replace("-", "");
            number = Integer.valueOf(text);
            if (number >= minValue && number <= maxValue) 
                return number;
            else {
                System.out.println("Number out of limit");
                number = askInteger(askedValue, minValue, maxValue);
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Please use only numbers");
            number = askInteger(askedValue);
        }
        return number;
    }
```

Comment: are you writing a console application or it is a spring app ?

Answer (score 2):

Yes. You use JavaDocs on your method to tell other developers what your method allows as parameters. Then, inside your method, you enforce that.

```
/**
 * [method description here]
 * 
 * @param askedValue
 * @param minValue   Min value. Must be smaller than <code>maxValue</code>
 * @param maxValue   Max value. Must be greater than <code>minValue</code>
 * @throws IllegalArgumentException If min value and max value are inconsistent.
 */
public static int askInteger(String askedValue, int minValue, int maxValue) {
    if (minValue >= maxValue)
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("maxValue must be > minValue");

   //[the rest of your method]
}
```

This is the standard way of letting your callers know what to expect. It's a contract that you document and enforce. IDEs will help them see the documentation at development time.